# An algorithm for pairing within a set

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

I have $2n$ countries and I want to pair them and have $n$ groups according to Euclidean distance, for instance, I want to minimize the sum of Euclidean distances. I have a $2n \times 2n$ symmetric matrix of distances. Is there an algorithm which allows me to do that? I have tried Hungarian, however, given that my input matrix is symmetric, the resulting matrix is not always symmetric.

Comment: I haven't really understood what you want to do exactly.  Could you try to phrase the question more precisely?

Comment: @Tara B: I want to divide $2n$ countries into $n$ pairs. My objective function is the sum of Euclidean distances between pair members. For instance, assume that we have 4 countries, namely, A, B, C and D. There are 2 possible combinations of pairing: ({A,B} and {C,D}) or ({A,C} and {B,D}). I would choose the first combination if $d(A,B) + d(C,D) < d(A,C) + d(B,D)$, where $d$ is Euclidean distance between two contries. I have a $2n \times 2n$ matrix where distances for all possible combinations are calculated. Given this matrix I want to divide $2n$ contries into $n$ pairs.

Comment: OK, thanks, that clarified the question.  I think maybe I was mainly confused by the 'for instance' in your first sentence.

Comment: @Tara B: This is because I can minimize a sum of squared distances or something similar as well.

Answer (score 2):

The term to search is "weighted Euclidean matching" or "minimum weight Euclidean matching". There are some algorithms, there also are many heuristics. I recommend starting with [this nice survey](http://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/fall08/cps234/projects/sayan_proj.pdf).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will check it. Could you tell me more keywords given that I am interested in matching within a set?

Comment: @Kolibris What do you mean by "within a set"?

Comment: I mean that I do not analyse the situation when, for instance, employees are matched with the tasks. Then we analyse a bipartite graph, since we have two sets, namely, employees and tasks. In my problem I have one set, namely, countries.

Comment: @Kolibris Well, for that you have "non-bipartite case" part of the survey I have linked. You might also want to consider searching for "general case".